# Perl comment block pop-up in eclipse Perl EPIC plugin

Tags: eclipse, perl, autocomplete, comments

How do I see the comment blocks above a sub I am calling while typing the sub name out in eclipse?

example is

```
$collector->get_collection();
```

right after I type `->` the option list for all the sub calls shows up but when I scroll through each one I do not see the comments that go with that sub above the function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is more a question for superuser? Anyway.

Unfortunately, this does not work.
There is no integrated print documentation/comment functionality in epic, at least for this kind of information.
I would like to have it, too!

The only documentation you can get inline is for perl builtins. When you double-click on a word, let's say `system`, you get a tooltip window with the short form of the
`perldoc -f system` call.
That's all.

You can get more documentation for modules or classes, when you mark a module (name) and call Help->Perldoc (or hitting F1 in my case), but not for functions or methods.
Then you get the perldoc in a different window.

What I do in your case:
Mark the method (after having written it) and hit F3, i.e. Open Declaration. It will jump to the `sub` and you can read the documentation. With the back keystroke or "Go to last edit location" I come back where I was.
This works as long as epic knows about the functions and methods, that is somewhat like:
 - the module with the function has to be in your Projects Perl Include Path
 - you have a use in your file for that module and the name is unique
 - you use fully qualified function names
 - you build your objects with `My::Class->new` instead of `new My::Class`.

Hope it helps at least a bit.

Comment: 2018 - and ``I would like to have it, too!`` ... Other small e.g php-IDEs have this functionality.